# How can I use one view controller with different Realm classes

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to create an app where I have 4 buttons which each one corresponds to a different category. Now the categories are different Realm Objects saved in a swift file.

```
class HealthData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
}

class SelfImprovement: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
}

class TopSecret: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
}

class Ohter: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
}
```

Now my problem is that I want a single view controller with a TableView to have different data that will get passed on to TableView from the corresponding category.

My idea was that I can create the `var categories : Results<HealthData>!` and use an if statement to change the categories to be Results etc using the prepare for a segue to know which button was pressed.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if categoryNo == 1 {
            title = "Health"
        } else if categoryNo == 2 {
            title = "Self Improvement"
            categories = Results<SelfImprovement>!
        }
    }
```

But of course, XCode cannot assign the value of type 'Results?.Type' to type 'Results?'.

Any ideas?

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: You can use `Model Inheritance` with `Realm`.

Comment: I didn’t quiet understand what you’re trying to do but you get the error because your categories variable is actually a type. Add () after Results<SelfImprovment>! And the error will go away...

Comment: Thank you a lot for the information and I know that it is quite complicated. But all I am trying to do is to have only one TableView that it is linked to different buttons. And the button that gets pressed will show on the table view the corresponding data without copy and pasting while only changing the Results to be <SelfImprovement> or whatever else. I can link the GitHub link if anyone is interested. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is you want to re-use the tableView to display data from different tableView datasources. You're heading down the right path but the answer is to tell the tableView where to get it's data from.

I am pairing this down to really basic code so don't copy paste - trying to keep it short.

Assume we have a view controller with a tableView

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: NSTableView!

var myHealthArray = [String]() //one tableview datasource
var mySelfImprovementArray = [String]() //another tableview datasource
var tableType = "" //will tell the tableView what it should be displaying
```

then, further down, we have the tableView delegate methods that populate the tableview

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    if self.tableType == "health" {
        return self.myHealthArray.count
    } else if self.tableType == "self_improvement" {
        return self.mySelfImprovementArray.count
    } //etc
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: myIdentifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    var s = ""
    if self.tableType == "health" {
        s = self.myHealthArray[row]
    } else if self.tableType == "self_improvement" {
        s = self.mySelfImprovementArray[row]
    } //etc
    cell.textField?.stringValue = s
    return cell
}
```

So the idea here is to set the tableType to whatever is supposed to be displayed in the tableView then the logic within the tableView delegate methods will know which dataSource array to get its data from.

It's important to remember that Realm Results are homogenous so they can only store one type of object.

In this example, I defined the dataSources as strings but in your case they may be realm results objects. If they are strings, you could just re-use the array as it would only contain string objects. However, if the dataSources are Realm Results, you'll need separate arrays as shown in this answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot Jay! I was thinking of doing something like this but I didn't do it just to avoid too many if statements but since this is the only solution it works perfectly.